# PHP - variable in "" not showing up

Tags: php

I want to show user names in profile but those who have `"` character in name not showing.

```
if(isset($_GET['User_Profile']))
{             
    $Query = 
        'SELECT 
            '.$User['Username'].'
        FROM 
            '.$DB_Table.' 
        WHERE 
            '.$User['Username'].'= :User_Profile
        ';
    $GetData = $Database->prepare($Query);
    $GetData->execute
                (
                array(
                    ':User_Profile' => $_GET['User_Profile'] 
                    )
                );
    $ShowData = $GetData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
```

To show name am using this and its working fine `echo $ShowData[ $User['Username'] ];`

There now its fine other user profile names are showing up but not those who have "javed" type name.

Please can someone tell me the solution?

Comment: `$User['Username']` contains a column name, not a user name?

Comment: Is ` "javed" ` out put of  `$User['Username']` or `$ShowData[ $User['Username'] ]`?

Comment: $ShowData[ $User['Username']] column name exist in database. and i want to show it as it is in database.

Comment: Sorry in database the text contains '''' quotes not ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See htmlentities(), which you should be using for any text that you are outputing as content that will be rendered by a HTML Browser. http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php, eg:

```
echo htmlentities($ShowData[$User['Username']], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: This is a good recommendation, but you don't need entities for doublequote characters. So there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

iconv — Convert string to requested character encoding

This is an example:

```
<?php
$text = "This is the Euro symbol '€'.";

echo 'Original : ', $text, PHP_EOL;
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Plain    : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text), PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Refer here...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 0):

print out put something like this

```
<?php echo htmlentities($User['Username']);
```

Comment: Yes only in h1 its not showing and making other texts also bug, still not working.

Comment: check if any css problem view source and check